# Sending an image to node server and calling OCR microsoft vision API

Tags: android, node.js, ocr, image-uploading, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to send an image(captured by phone camera) from an android device to a nodeJS server and then from there to call microsoft OCR. 
Technique i'm following is, image is compressed, get the byte array and send to the node server using HTTP POST method, from the node server, just getting the byte array from the request and call the API.

here's the used process:
1). get the Bitmap image

2). create the HTTP request as follows:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, output);
byte[] bufAry = output.toByteArray();

dos.write( bufAry, 0, bufAry.length);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

dos.flush();
```

from the node side here's the code:

```
router.post('/', rawBody, function(req, res, next)
{
    console.log("post request");
    if (req.rawBody && req.bodyLength > 0) {
        sendRequestForOCR(req.rawBody, res );

    } else {
        res.send(500);
    }

});

function rawBody(req, res, next) {
    var chunks = [];

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);

        req.bodyLength = buffer.length;
        req.rawBody = buffer;
        next();
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500);
    });
}

function sendRequestForOCR( image, res ) {

    var encodedImg = querystring.stringify({
        data: image
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'api.projectoxford.ai',
        path: '/vision/v1.0/ocr',
        port: '80',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'my_key'
        }
    };

    var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            res.send('ok');
        })
    });
    httpreq.write(encodedImg);
    httpreq.end();
}
```

But when executed the message i'm getting is:

```
"code":"InvalidImageFormat", "message":"Input data is not a valid image."
```

can anyone please let me know what is the issue in the code?
Is it the compressing of the image or issue in the streaming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're really only set to handle one image at a time, you should modify the Java code to simply send the JPG bytes raw, without the multipart MIME.  As your code is written, the payload that the nodejs server receives contains the additional decoration that multipart MIME requires (boundary, name, etc.).  So:

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());    
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, output);
byte[] bufAry = output.toByteArray();

dos.write(bufAry, 0, bufAry.length);    
dos.flush();
```

One option is for this Java code to call directly to the Microsoft Cognitive Services URL.  If, however, you need your intermediate nodejs server for some other processing, you'll want to pass the binary payload without modification.  In other words,

```
function sendRequestForOCR( image, res ) {

    var options = {
        host: 'api.projectoxford.ai',
        path: '/vision/v1.0/ocr'
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'my_key'
        }
    };

    var httpreq = https.request(options, function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            res.send('ok');
        })
    });
    httpreq.write(image);
    httpreq.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, As you pointed out, error was with how I was sending the byte array from android to node server and modifying the byte array before sending to microsoft-cognitive service from node.

After the proposed modifications, it works fine.